# How can I access RedirectAttributes in a method without RedirectAttributes in its signature?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In a Spring Boot controller, is it possible to access `RedirectAttributes` in a method without `RedirectAttributes` in its signature?  In other words, can it be accessed from the framework as a "bean" or context variable?

My motivation for doing this is to be able to refactor several request mapping methods (à la *Clean Code*) to move exception handling out of those methods.  So, for example, I have several methods with a `catch` block like this:

```java
    @GetMapping("/security/user/{uid}")
    public String showEditUserForm(@PathVariable("uid") String uid, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        try {
            model.addAttribute("userAccount", userAccountService.findByUsername(uid));
            return "/security/edituser";
        } catch(UserDoesntExistException e) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashstatus","danger");
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashmessage","User doesn't exist");
            return "redirect:/security";
        }
    }
```

Instead, I'd like to do something like this:

```java
    @GetMapping("/security/user/{uid}")
    public String showEditUserForm(@PathVariable("uid") String uid, Model model) {
        try {
            model.addAttribute("userAccount", userAccountService.findByUsername(uid));
            return "/security/edituser";
        } catch(UserDoesntExistException e) {
            return redirectWithMessage("danger","User doesn't exist");
        }
    }

    // and several other mappings that also call redirectWithMessage()

    public String redirectWithMessage(String status, String message) {
        // obtain RedirectAttributes somehow!
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashstatus",status);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashmessage",message);
        return "redirect:/security";
    }
```

**So the question is, how can the utility method ("`redirectWithMessage`") obtain a pointer to `RedirectAttributes` without every method in the class having to have it in its signature and pass it along via injection?**

Comment: Personally I would prefer to pass the `RedirectAttributes` from your controller methods due to Clean Code itself - is is much more understandable for future developers, where from you get this variable from. Furthermore, this way you can guarantee, that you work with RedirectAttributes and request that you expect and not with some other which happens to be the last request available at specific point of time when your `redirectWithMessage()` method is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of ways with [`RequestContextUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html):

1. Call `RequestContextUtils#getOutputFlashMap` to get access to the flash map and update them (attributes + target redirect)
2. Call convenient method `RequestContextUtils#saveOutputFlashMap`
3. You can get instance of `FlashMapManager`

Invoke this method to write flash attributes:

> Save the given FlashMap, in some underlying storage and set the start of its expiration period.
>   NOTE: Invoke this method prior to a redirect in order to allow saving the FlashMap in the HTTP session or in a response cookie before the response is committed.

```
void saveOutputFlashMap(FlashMap flashMap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

You can gain access to current request/response by `@Autowire` them into the bean.

For your usecase, stick with #1 is OK (just add the attributes, the redirect location is set on your return string already)

Example:

```
@Autowired
HttpServletRequest request;

public String redirectWithMessage(String status, String message) {
   FlashMap flashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request);

   flashMap.put("flashstatus",status);
   flashMap.put("flashmessage",message);

   return "redirect:/security";
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a complete `redirectWithMessage(String status, String message)` method for me to use?